# How to display html content on UIWebView IOS

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, nsmutablestring

I have a form sheet segue that should display hard-coded html page.
Now I have a two part problem first problem is

```
 <CENTER><H1>A Simple Sample Web Page</H1><H4>By Frodo</H4>
<H2>Demonstrating a few HTML features</H2></CENTER>
```

is displayed like

[image]

I can change `<CENTER>`tag to `<left>` in that case it works but it limits my options. How can I display this content In the middle of the screen without alignment issues?

Second part of the question is How can I embed a color or a link to content. On line  `""FFFFFF">\n"` I get the error that says `Expected ':'` and on line `"<a href="http://somegreatsite.com">\n"` Half of the line is green which is seems like comment on the screen that means it will not executed by XCode

My full code is like :

```
- (void) createWebViewWithHTML{
    //create the string
    NSMutableString *html = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"<html><head><title></title></head><body style=\"background:transparent;\">"];

    //continue building the string
    [html appendString:@"<BODY BGCOLOR="
     ""FFFFFF">\n"
     "<CENTER><IMG SRC="clouds.jpg" ALIGN="BOTTOM">
     "</CENTER> \n"
     "<HR>\n"
     "<a href="http://somegreatsite.com">\n"
     "Link Name</a>\n"

     "is a link to another nifty site\n"

     "<H1>This is a Header</H1>\n"

     "<H2>This is a Medium Header</H2>\n"

     "Send me mail at <a href="mailto:support@yourcompany.com">\n"

     "support@yourcompany.com</a>.\n"

     "<P> This is a new paragraph!\n"

     "<P> <B>This is a new paragraph!</B>\n"

     "<BR> <B><I>This is a new sentence without a paragraph break, in bold italics.</I></B>\n"

     "<HR>\n"];
    [html appendString:@"</body></html>"];

    //instantiate the web view
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];


    //make the background transparent
    [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    //pass the string to the webview
    [webView loadHTMLString:[html description] baseURL:nil];

    //add it to the subview
    [self.view addSubview:webView];

}
```

Edit::
Added story board picture

[image]

**So how can I make correct alignment and embed color/link correctly?**

Comment: try giving webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view. **bounds** ]; instead of frame

Comment: Why `[html description]`
 instead of just `html`?

Comment: isnt that how you pass string to webview ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Check if your `UIWebView` has the right size. It seems to be bigger than the screen.
2. Place a \ before any " in your hard-coded string.
   e.g.:

   ```
   NSString *testString="This is a \"Test\"";
   ```

   results in

   > This is a "Test"

Hope this helps

Comment: it seems size doesnt matter :), that is what she said ha:)  I have changed it few times but it is not recognized by Xcode. Added picture on question

Comment: changing code to `webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.webView.frame];` and adding \ worked for me thank you